# Search for places around current location of the user - PlaceAutocompleteFragment

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

What I need to do is implementing a `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` view to look for places around the  user's current location.

I was taking a look at the official documentation but couldn't find a proper way to do it.

I've set a `Place.TYPE_COUNTRY` filter but it shows predictions of places all around the country and most of the results shown when typing are irrelevant for the user.

```
   AutocompleteFilter filter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setTypeFilter(Place.TYPE_COUNTRY)
            .setCountry(country)
            .build();
```

The `PlaceAutocompleteFragment.setBoundsBias(LatLngBounds)` method provides a way to restrict results to a specific region.

```
autocompleteFragment.setBoundsBias(new LatLngBounds(
        new LatLng(-33.880490, 151.184363),
        new LatLng(-33.858754, 151.229596)));
```

According to the documentation the code above restricts results to a specific region of Sydney, Australia. I think this is similar to what I want to get.

So the question is, is there a way to get the `LatLng` values to instantiate the `LatLngBounds` object programatically?

I mean, I want to get that values dinamically based on the current location of the user.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just need the device's location? If so see [Making Your App Location-Aware](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html). You can then expand this into a bounding rect (one way is to use [`SphericalUtil.computeOffset()`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/) from the [android-maps-utils](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) library)

Finally, note that the bounds is not a strict restrict on results, it only *biases* results to the bounds.

Or are you asking how to find out what a good bounds would be to use for an arbitrary city/region in the world where the device is located? If so, then you could do the following

1. Do a reverse geocode lookup on the device's location using the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro).
2. Examine the results and pick the result at locality level?
3. Use the `viewport` of that result as the bounds.

Comment: I just want to apply kind of a filter in the place autocomplete fragment to show predictions of places only around the current location of the user.  By applying the TYPE_COUNTRY filter it shows places all aroud the country, these entries are not useful for the users since they only want to look for nearby places.

Comment: In that case, the first suggestion in my answer should do what you want.

Comment: yeah you're right, I'll do that and let you know the result in a few days as soon as I get it done.